Understanding "message format version" in logs
Following logs are shared on the following link
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,917] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-39, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,917] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-39, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,919] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-10-27 15:09:19,920] INFO [Log partition=__consumer_offsets-21, dir=/home/ajinkya/software/Kaftka/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/Kafka-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.Log)

Decoding Apache Kafka Logs
What is the meaning of message format version 2 here, what is the version of kafka being used here what is the log.message.format.version of broker and how to check how this message format version is set ?
